# Cannot add XML Schema to XML document for VBA Validation

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate an XML document using the schema provided online by the FCA.

In the xml file the schema is defined in the headers like this:

```
<PSD007-MortgagePerformanceSalesData xmlns = "urn:fsa-gov-uk:MER:PSD007:1" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:fsa-gov-uk:MER:PSD007:1 
        http://www.fsa.gov.uk/mer/drg/PSD007/v1-3/PSD007-Schema.xsd"
```

I want to provide the users with a tool to validate the xml generated by our macro before they load the xml file into the FCA Reporting system.

So I took the code from [tomalak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18771/tomalak)'s answer in [SO: MSXML VBA: Validating XML against XSD: “The '' namespace provided differs from the schema's targetNamespace.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708492/msxml-vba-validating-xml-against-xsd-the-namespace-provided-differs-from-t)

Here is my modified version of the code:

```
Sub XSD_Validation()
    Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim objSchemaCache As New XMLSchemaCache60
    Dim objErr As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError

    objSchemaCache.Add "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" & Chr
(34) & " xsi:schemaLocation=" & Chr(34) & "urn:fsa-gov-uk:MER:PSD007:1 
http://www.fsa.gov.uk/mer/drg/PSD007/v1-3/PSD007-Schema.xsd", LoadXmlFile
("C:\PRA Export Data Jul 17 2015.xml")

    Set xmlDoc = LoadXmlFile("C:\PRA Export Data Jul 17 2015.xml")
    Set xmlDoc.Schemas = objSchemaCache

    Set objErr = xmlDoc.Validate()
    If objErr.ErrorCode = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "No errors found"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Error parser: " & objErr.ErrorCode & "; " & objErr.reason
    End If
End Sub
```

When I run the code I get the below error:

> PRA%20Export%20Data%20Jul%2017%202015.xml#/PSD007-MortgagePerformanceSalesData
>   Incorrect definition for the root element in schema.

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some careful checking of the answer provided by tomalak on the other question, I resolved this.

In fact the first argument of `objSchemaCache.Add` should be the *target namespace* which is **urn:fsa-gov-
    uk:MER:PSD007:1** and the second argument should be *the location of the schema file* which is **http://www.fsa.gov.uk/mer/drg/PSD007/v1-3/PSD007-Schema.xsd**

So when I used

```
    objSchemaCache.Add "urn:fsa-gov-
uk:MER:PSD007:1", "http://www.fsa.gov.uk/mer/drg/PSD007/v1-3/PSD007-Schema.xsd"
```

it works, and now tells me that the file does not validate (which is correct!)