# VBA code to validate XML using XSD files and retrieving all validation errors in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba, validation, xsd

I am building an application using Excel VBA to validate xml files against xsd. I used below code snipped and added to my application.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11709428/8854979

Now, the problem I am facing is, it doesn't provide full list of validation errors, instead it gives me only first error encountered.

While searching on Internet I came to know that I can use 'IXMLDOMParseError2' object with property allErrors, see below;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759143(v=vs.85).aspx

this will give me list of all errors during xml validation.

I just wanted to know how to use this in VBA code.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but hopefully this will help someone:

```
' PURPOSE:                                                                      '
' Validate XML Doc against Schema                                               '
Sub validateXDoc(ByRef xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60)                          '

    Const SCHEMA_LOCATION As String = "C:\mySchema.xsd"
    Dim SCHEMA_NAMESPACE As String
    SCHEMA_NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"


    Dim objSchemaCache As New XMLSchemaCache60
    Dim objErr As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError2

    objSchemaCache.Add SCHEMA_NAMESPACE, LoadXmlFile(SCHEMA_LOCATION)

    With xmlDoc
        Set .schemas = objSchemaCache
        .setProperty "MultipleErrorMessages", True
        Set objErr = .Validate()
    End With
    Dim oErr As Object

    For Each oErr In objErr.allErrors
        Debug.Print "Error parser: " & oErr.errorCode & "; " & oErr.reason
    Next oErr
End Sub
```

Comment: This code returns: Error parser: -1072897500; The node is neither valid nor invalid because no DTD/Schema declaration was found.

Answer (score 0):

Ypu can find syntax for the `MultipleErrorMessages` Property on [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764619(v=vs.85).aspx).  Something like this should work for you:

```
xmlDoc.setProperty("MultipleErrorMessages", TRUE)
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives me a syntax error, with message "Compile error: Expected: ="

Comment: Can you give me an example in VBA to retrieve all XML validation errors using XSD file. I want to list all error details and print them in excel worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example (just improvised on previous answers) > No errors this time.

```
    Sub validateXMLDoc()
       'Schema
            Const SCHEMA_LOCATION As String = "C:\xsd.xsd"
            Dim SCHEMA_NAMESPACE As String
            SCHEMA_NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            
            Dim objSchemaCache
            Set objSchemaCache = New XMLSchemaCache60
            objSchemaCache.Add SCHEMA_NAMESPACE, SCHEMA_LOCATION
      
            Dim objerr As MSXML2.IXMLDOMParseError2
           
       'XML Document     
            Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
            Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
            Set xmlDoc.Schemas = objSchemaCache
            xmlDoc.async = False ': xmlDoc.validateOnParse = False
            xmlDoc.Load ("D:\xmlfilename.xml")
           
            With xmlDoc
                .setProperty "MultipleErrorMessages", True
                Set objerr = .Validate()
            End With
            Dim oErr As Object
        'Error code : Reason along with Line Number
            For Each oErr In objerr.allErrors
                MsgBox "Error parser: "& " " & oErr.Line & oErr.ErrorCode & "; " & oErr.reason
            Next oErr
        
            Set xmlDoc = Nothing
    End Sub
```